# Can I install a p-trap with AAV onto a horizontal sewer line?

Tags: plumbing, drain, sewer, p-trap

I currently have a standpipe for a dryer (no p-trap and unvented) which connects (via some elbows) to a horizontal sewer line in the basement. I would like to (a) install a p-trap in the basement underneath and (b) drain condensate of my HPWH.

Please see the current setup along with a picture on the left. On the right, how I would want to install a part like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09Q6F5KD4). As far as I know this would not be perfectly compliant because the washer should have 2". Hence I would consider building exactly the same myself out of PVC or ABS fittings.

[image]

*Note*: As far as I know AAVs **are** allowed where I live (San Mateo, California), but even if not, it would only improve the situation. I do not have the resources to create another vent or to connect to the vent from the BR sink. It is buried inside the wall and I do not want to open the wall.

Comment: what kind of HPWH do you have?  Rheem proterra?

Comment: Yes, Rheem Proterra!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The spirit of the code is such that if a clog were to appear after your AAV in the horizontal line then the debris laden water would fill the AAV and if it didn't leak there it would then push up and out your condensate surgical tubing back into your condensate pump.  Just having the debris laden water move into those places can cause crud to build up and plug those drains.

I'd drill a hole in the floor from the basement up to the washer stand pipe and use a dishwasher input so the condensate can be up higher than the next flood level - the top of the BR vented sink.  I'd put the p-trap per your plan.  I'd add another Y  for your AAV but take it up to the floor above and have the AAV at a level above the washer standpipe.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is the reason why you'd put the AAV all the way up so that you avoid filling the AAV in case of a clog? Then I will still need to cut the wall open. Is there no way without? Finally, what's the reason you'd route the condensate all the way up, rather than draining it as I showed?

Comment: One more question: Do you have a reference what a "dishwasher input" is?

Comment: Dishwasher Y with 1/2" inlet.  Yes the backup and then clog potential potentially also leak on AAV I don't know if those would be water tight.

Comment: what is the distance between your vertical riser for the washer and the vented BR sink, is the sink vent a straight run up to the roof?  You might be fine with wet venting the p-trap from that vent.  https://www.jlconline.com/how-to/plumbing/maximum-length-for-fixture-drains_o

Comment: sounds promising! Distance is a bit less than 3ft. Yes, vent is straight run to roof as far as I can tell (except the sanitary tee for the sink itself). Having said that, seems I have the opposite problem: I am measuring a slope between 0 and 1 degree. Much too small I think

Comment: I was at the Home Depot today but for my life of it could not find this “dishwasher Y”. Would you mind sharing a link to such a part? I also purchased a 20ft, 12” OD drain hose but I’m not clear yet how to attach it to the drain. Will I just let it hang in or is there a special coupling I should get?

Comment: https://pexhouse.com/product/1-1-2-x-1-1-2-x-1-2-abs-dishwasher-y/

Comment: seems like HD usa just sells it as a tail piece....   homedepot.ca has them....   I've used them for condensate attachments quite a few times.  There are 1 1/2" bushings to 1/2" barb that install into standard abs Ys as well.

Comment: Sorry another followup question: I have everything now but I am somewhat hesitant to drill another hole in my floor. What is the exact reason you’d want to bring up the condensate drain one flow higher as opposed to putting the condensate drain directly into the sewer in the basement?

Comment: you have 2 vertical wdv joining with a horizontal wdv.  if you get a clog on the far left of the horizontal pipe then all effluent will rise until it hits the first point of exit.  your image 2 has both the aav and the condensate lines as the lower point so the effluent will work to clog your aav and back up into your hpwt.  if you put the condensate drain above this point then something else is lower.  ideally a bathtub is the lowest point so sewer cleanup is easier.  worst case is sewer main backs up and then you have other peoples waste backing up into your hpwt condensate pump / etc.

Comment: nastiest backup i had was with a toilet that i had turned the water supply off.  there was a low point the bathtub based shower.  the basement wasn't in use so the blockage didn't get detected for a while.  the sewer backed up the tub and clogged the tub drain...   the next lowest point was the rim of the toilet with the lid down.  the toilet overflowed and must also have clogged and the sewer backed up into the toilet water reservoir since there was no water already in there.  wrote that toilet off, smashed it into pieces - had some nice juicy liquid poo filling the p-trap.