# Which part do I need to connect a 1/2" OD 3/8" ID drain pipe to an 1/2" dishwasher wye?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, pipe-fitting

It sounds silly but it seems I can't just connect a 1/2" OD / 3/8" ID drainline to my 1/2" dishwasher wye.

I purchased [this one](https://pexhouse.com/product/1-1-2-x-1-1-2-x-1-2-abs-dishwasher-y/) which should be 1/2" but I measure roughly 5/8" OD.

Here is a closeup picture:

[image]

You can see there is no way I can attach this pipe.

Which part do I need to connect the two?

Also, can it be that they shipped the wrong part? Exactly the one in the link is what I ordered but what I got looks slightly different.

Comment: Hose/tubing sizes can be confusing, especially going by looks.  Usually you go by internal diameter, not outer diameter, and need to be the same type.  1/2 inch copper, black plastic and garden hose are different sizes.  A bit surprise they list O.D.

Comment: That's not dishwasher drain hose. I'd suggest taking it back to the Big Box store you got it from and asking for a dishwasher drain hose kit. That will get you going, if the dishwasher itself doesn't come with a drain hose (never seen a dishwasher without an included drain hose myself).

Comment: @Triplefault not from a BigBox store, I showed the link where I ordered. I don’t want to connect dishwasher , I want to connect condensate drain of HP/HPWH. That pump has exactly the hose shown in the picture

Comment: Ah, I should have read more carefully. Everbuilt is also sold at Home Depot.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 3/8 drain hose, not a 1/2 ".

If that is the proper drain for the dishwasher, ( usually the hose is of a larger diameter.) then you need a wye with a 3/8 nipple.  The other option is to find a 1/2 to 3/8 barbed reducer and a short piece of 1/2 inch ID hose.

Comment: I don't think that *is* the right drain for a d/w; it looks like just some generic vinyl drain tubing to me.  OP, what is this tube supposed to actually drain?

Comment: agreed, @Huesmann, that is generic tubing from Big Box, not a dishwasher drain tube.

Comment: @Huesmann no dishwasher, I want to drain condensate from HP/HPWH. This is follow up from my question here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/285918/can-i-install-a-p-trap-with-aav-onto-a-horizontal-sewer-line . First question is, did PEXhouse send the right thing? (The picture in my link looks different than the picture I took)

Comment: @RMDman got it. Is this the right part? https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-2-in-Barb-x-3-8-in-MIP-Nylon-Adapter-Fitting-800219/300862732 seems would be easier to get a new wye …

Comment: NO that part is a 3/8 barb to a 1/2" threaded adapter.   You need a 1/2 barb to 3/8 barb reducer and a short piece of 1/2 inch tubing.

Comment: Where is your HPWH located in relation to this sink?

Comment: @Huesmann in the basement below the washing machine (standpipe)

Comment: What's in the basement—the sink or the HPWH?